# Plate boundary lon/lat data

Tags: geophysics, plate-tectonics, geodesy

I'm working on a map in GMT and am having trouble finding lon/lat data for the minor plate boundaries (specifically the adriatic). Is there a database I can refer to?

Comment: https://gcmd.nasa.gov/KeywordSearch/Metadata.do?Portal=NASA&KeywordPath=Parameters%7COCEANS&OrigMetadataNode=GCMD&EntryId=NASA_DTAM&MetadataView=Full&MetadataType=0&lbnode=mdlb2 may or may not be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a little poking around and came across a few projects that might be interesting.

Based on the work of [Peter Bird (2003)](https://doi.org/10.1029/2001GC000252) there's a github project ([fraxen/tectonicplates](https://github.com/fraxen/tectonicplates)) that hosts georeferenced data of most major plate boundaries.

Seeing as you're interested more in minor plate dynamics, there's another project called [GPlates](http://www.gplates.org/) that is an multi-OS open source visualizer for plate boundary dynamic reconstructions. While I haven't looked at the potential outputs available, I imagine you would be able to export data from this platform into a more traditional GIS data format (.shp, .gml) that could be read in GMT.

Comment: Thank you, GPlates is a great resource! This is exactly what I was looking for!